# I want to calculate how many times each product was ordered each year but keep getting an error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count how many orders there was for each product, by using the line of code below

```
TSP_Order = TSP_Order.groupby(['ProdName','Year']).count('OrderID')
```

But i receive the error below

```
TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

An example of my dataset

| ProdName | OrderID | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toy Car | 1 | 2015 |
| Puzzle | 1 | 2015 |
| Toy Car | 2 | 2015 |
| Train Set | 2 | 2015 |
| Toy Car | 3 | 2016 |
| Puzzle | 4 | 2016 |
| Toy Car | 5 | 2016 |
| Train Set | 5 | 2016 |

I want to calculate how many times each product was ordered per year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. After grouping on the fields of interest, you need to access the column of interest, here `OrderID`, and perform the statistic you need (simple count in this case):

```
df.groupby(['ProdName','Year'])['OrderID'].count()

ProdName   Year
Puzzle     2015    1
           2016    1
Toy Car    2015    2
           2016    2
Train Set  2015    1
           2016    1
Name: OrderID, dtype: int64
```

with

```
df

    ProdName  OrderID  Year
0    Toy Car        1  2015
1     Puzzle        1  2015
2    Toy Car        2  2015
3  Train Set        2  2015
4    Toy Car        3  2016
5     Puzzle        4  2016
6    Toy Car        5  2016
7  Train Set        5  2016
```

Comment: How did you copy the dataset from the question and pasted it in a way that you created a data frame from it?

Comment: I am using pycharm and am very fast at editing multiple lines simultaneously, meaning it was copy/paste based.

Comment: Please share piece of code where you created dataframe.

Comment: deponovo is it still possible to use a disinct count in the same line of code for another column ?

Comment: @se9tlr you can use any statistic (for instance `mean`, `std`, `sum`, etc) for any other possibly existing column in the exact same way.